# Error while executing power shell on windows from UNIX through ssh

Tags: windows, unix, ssh

I am trying to trigger powershell script residing on windows server from unix through **ssh**

SSH command:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "powershell "D:\\Script\\file\\location\\test.ps1" source_file target_file"
```

Powershell test script:

```
param([string]$inputFile, [string]$outputFile)
Write-Host "INPUT: " $inputFile
Write-Host "OUTPUT: " $outputFile
Exit
```

However, once the powershell completes the execution the control is not returning back to unix prompt.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "echo '\n' |  powershell 'D:\\Script\\file\\location\\test.ps1' source_file target_file"
```